# AWS Step Functions: calling API Gateway endpoint with URL parameter is ignored

Tags: aws-step-functions

In Step Functions workflow, I have a state in which I am trying to call an API endpoint `/v1/map?json=1` but the problem is `json=1` is not getting picked up. It appears only `/v1/map` gets passed checking the CloudWatch Logs.

```json
    {
      "Type": "Task",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:states:::apigateway:invoke",
      "Parameters": {
        "ApiEndpoint": "asdf.execute-api.us-east-1.amazonaws.com",
        "Method": "POST",
        "Stage": "dev",
        "Path": "/v1/map?json",
        "Headers": {
          "Accept": [
            "application/json"
          ]
        },
        "Stage": "dev",
        "AuthType": "IAM_ROLE"
      },
      "Next": "Lambda Invoke",
      "ResultPath": "$.myStateInput"
    }
```

Is passing URL parameters not supported? What happens if I don't pass any value to `isJson` and just do `?isJson` would that also get ignored?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Query Paramaters are accepted](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/step-functions/latest/dg/connect-api-gateway.html#connect-api-gateway-requests-optional), just not as part of the `Path`:

```json
"QueryParameters": {
    "json": ["1"]
},
```

Comment: seems kinda crazy, I'm finding the custom language they built not very intuitive and just too verbose, I'm going crazy working inside that tiny beta studio editor